# Problem with OneDrive and Sites links after migrating Sharepoint 2013 from HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: alternate-access-mapping, ssl

I created a Sharepoint test environment with HTTP originally. Now I am switching everything over to SSL. I had both a "home" web application for the main collaboration site, and a my sites web application.

This is Sharepoint 2013 SP1 with all cumulative updates through April.

Following the Technet suggestions, I unextended the IIS sites, and then re-extended with SSL enabled. Everything is great for 2 users who had already logged on to the site (my test account and the sharepoint install account), but not for my own primary account that I had been using to test the site with.

For my account, the HTTPS site works fine, but the links to the Onedrive and promoted sites are both pointing to the old URL, the HTTP url.

Is there some way to fix this? A job that I need to run?

I tried deleting my My Site and then recreating it, but didn't change anything.

I did update the path to My Sites in the User Profile Application, and the Newsfeed link is correct for all users that I have tested with. Only the OneDrive and Sites links are wrong.

Under Alternate Access Mappings for both sites, there is only one entry: the default zone, which is correctly set to https://

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does it act for a user that has never been on your mysite before?  If it works for them and not for you, it might have something to do with the suitelinks using html5 localstorage to cache them.  See this link for how to clear out your localstorage:

http://feedback.weather.com/knowledgebase/articles/27908-managing-cookies-and-html5-local-storage-on-your

Comment: Can't believe how long I spent on this--you are exactly right. After I cleared the HTML5 local storage cache, the links were correct.

Comment: Yea, I spent a lot of time try to figure it out as well. :)